# solution for stopping the spinning numbers in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, spinner

```
 happyCustomers = 0;
 followers = 0;
 awardsWinning = 0;
 photosTaken = 0;
 arrayOfImages = [];
 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
   Observable.interval(400).subscribe(x => {
 this.happyCustomers = this.happyCustomers + 1;
  });
   Observable.interval(200).subscribe(x => {
  this.followers = this.followers + 1;
  });
   Observable.interval(700).subscribe(x => {
  this.awardsWinning = this.awardsWinning + 1;
  });
   Observable.interval(300).subscribe(x => {
   this.photosTaken = this.photosTaken + 1;
 });
}
```

here i am adding + 1 evrytime and it does not stop, when i reach a certain data count it should stop the count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [take](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-take) method.

> `take` method takes the first `count` values from the source, then completes.
>
> Call it before subscription.

```js
const certainNumber = 10;

Observable.interval(400)
  .take(certainNumber)
  .subscribe(_ => this.happyCustomers++);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a hardcoded value, you can use the take() command.

Example :

```
Observable.interval(400)
          .take(500)
          .subscribe(x => {
               this.happyCustomers = this.happyCustomers + 1;
          });
```

The above code will stop after 500 events have been emitted.

See http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-take

Comment: any imports for take();

Comment: You should invoke `take` method before subscription.

Comment: Slight typo from my end. Fixed the answer. Thnks for pointing it out!